# How to fix types duplicates?

Tags: typescript, webrtc

i want to build typescript and it throws `Duplicate identifier`.

What is the problem, i want to have access to WebRTC types. In my compilerOptions `tsconfig.hson` I have

```
"lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "dom.iterable", "dom", "scripthost"],
```

I need `dom`. If i add `"@types/webrtc": "0.0.21",` to dependencies then it says `Duplicate identifier` on most parts.

If I don't do it then `RTCDataChannel` data is undefined and the parts that were throwing duplicates are ok.

I need `RTCDataChannel` how can i add it without duplicates error. ?

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": ".code",
    "newLine": "LF",
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017", "dom.iterable", "dom", "scripthost"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "es",
    "lib"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with an setting `compilerOptions` in **tsconfig.json** `"skipLibCheck": true`.

What it does is

> Skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts).